# Matrix to the power 100 by Cayley Hamilton

Tags: matrices, cayley-hamilton

I have the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  1 & −1 \\ −1 & −1 &  0 \\  0 & −1&  0\end{pmatrix}$$

with characteristic polynomial $p(x)=-x^3 + x - 2$
and I have to find $A^{100}$ with the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: What have you tried? What does Cayley-Hamilton say? Have you seen similar examples before?

Comment: Either you copied the matrix wrong, or you made a mistake with the characteristic polynomial.  I suspect the latter, since the actual characteristic polynomial of this matrix makes the question easy.

Comment: In fact, the actual characteristic polynomial of the given matrix is $x^3+1$, hence $$A^{100} = (A^3)^{33}A = (-I)^{33}A = -A.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&\!-1\\\!-1&\!-1&0\\0&\!-1&0\end{pmatrix}\implies \det(xI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}x-1&\!-1&1\\1&x+1&0\\0&1&x\end{vmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=x(x^2-1)+x+1=x^3+1\implies\;\text{by C.H.,}\;A^3=-I\implies $$

$$A^{100}=(A^3)^{33}A=-A$$